# compare n-grams to group duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am working on a script that will consider two lines to be duplicate if three consecutive words between those two lines match.

Suppose my current dataset is:

```
1 A Course of Pure Mathematics by G. H. Hardy
2 Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices by Robert C. Martin
3 Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, 3rd Edition
4 Advanced Selling Strategies: Brian Tracy
5 Advanced Programming in the UNIX(R) Environment
6 Alex's Adventures in Numberland: Dispatches from the Wonderful World of Mathematics by Alex Bellos, Andy Riley
7 Advertising Secrets of the Written Word: The Ultimate Resource on How to Write Powerful Advertising
8 Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices
9 A Course of Pure Mathematics (Cambridge Mathematical Library) 10th Edition by G. H. Hardy 
10 Alex’s Adventures in Numberland
11 Advertising Secrets of the Written Word
12 Alex's Adventures in Numberland Paperback by Alex Bellos
```

Here, 1 & 9 is duplicate because `course pure mathematics` matches.
2 & 8 is duplicate because `advanced programming unix` matches.
3 & 5 is duplicate because `advanced programming unix` matches.
and so on ...

The script I have written so far is:

```
import re
from nltk.util import ngrams

OriginalBooksList = list()
booksAfterRemovingStopWords = list()
booksWithNGrams = list()
stopWords = ['I', 'a', 'about', 'an', 'are', 'as', 'at', 'be', 'by', 'com', 'for', 'from', 'how', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'that', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'was', 'the', 'and', 'A', 'About', 'An', 'Are', 'As', 'At', 'Be', 'By', 'Com', 'For', 'From', 'How', 'In', 'Is', 'It', 'Of', 'On', 'Or', 'That', 'The', 'This', 'To', 'Was', 'The', 'And']

wordsToSearch = list()

with open('UnifiedBookList.txt') as fin:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(fin):
        OriginalBooksList.append(line)
        line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',line) # remove punchuation with space
        line = re.sub(' +', ' ',line) # replace multiple space with one
        line = line.lower() # to lower case
        if line.strip() and len(line.split())>2: # line can not be empty and line must have more than 2 words 
            booksAfterRemovingStopWords.append(' '.join([i for i in line.split() if i not in stopWords])) # Remove Stop Words And Make Sentence
            # books.append(str(len(line.split())) + ' ' +line.strip()) # No Of Words In Book Name + Book Name 

for line_no, line in enumerate(booksAfterRemovingStopWords):
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    output = list(ngrams(tokens, 3))
    temp = list()

    temp.append(OriginalBooksList[line_no]) # Adding original line
    for x in output: # Adding n-grams
        temp.append(' '.join(x))
    booksWithNGrams.append(temp)

print(booksWithNGrams)

with open('BookListLatestCleanWithNGrams.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in booksWithNGrams:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

It clean-up the lines (replace punctuation with space, replace all lines to lowercase etc.).

Then create a trigram.

The output is given bellow:

```
[
['1 A Course of Pure Mathematics by G. H. Hardy\n', '1 course pure', 'course pure mathematics', 'pure mathematics g', 'mathematics g h', 'g h hardy'],
['2 Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices by Robert C. Martin\n', '2 agile software', 'agile software development', 'software development principles', 'development principles patterns', 'principles patterns practices', 'patterns practices robert', 'practices robert c', 'robert c martin'],
['3 Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, 3rd Edition\n', '3 advanced programming', 'advanced programming unix', 'programming unix environment', 'unix environment 3rd', 'environment 3rd edition'],
['4 Advanced Selling Strategies: Brian Tracy\n', '4 advanced selling', 'advanced selling strategies', 'selling strategies brian', 'strategies brian tracy'],
['5 Advanced Programming in the UNIX(R) Environment\n', '5 advanced programming', 'advanced programming unix', 'programming unix r', 'unix r environment'],
["6 Alex's Adventures in Numberland: Dispatches from the Wonderful World of Mathematics by Alex Bellos, Andy Riley\n", '6 alex s', 'alex s adventures', 's adventures numberland', 'adventures numberland dispatches', 'numberland dispatches wonderful', 'dispatches wonderful world', 'wonderful world mathematics', 'world mathematics alex', 'mathematics alex bellos', 'alex bellos andy', 'bellos andy riley'],
['7 Advertising Secrets of the Written Word: The Ultimate Resource on How to Write Powerful Advertising\n', '7 advertising secrets', 'advertising secrets written', 'secrets written word', 'written word ultimate', 'word ultimate resource', 'ultimate resource write', 'resource write powerful', 'write powerful advertising'],
['8 Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices\n', '8 agile software', 'agile software development', 'software development principles', 'development principles patterns', 'principles patterns practices'],
['9 A Course of Pure Mathematics (Cambridge Mathematical Library) 10th Edition by G. H. Hardy \n', '9 course pure', 'course pure mathematics', 'pure mathematics cambridge', 'mathematics cambridge mathematical', 'cambridge mathematical library', 'mathematical library 10th', 'library 10th edition', '10th edition g', 'edition g h', 'g h hardy'],
['10 Alex’s Adventures in Numberland\n', '10 alex s', 'alex s adventures', 's adventures numberland'],
['11 Advertising Secrets of the Written Word\n', '11 advertising secrets', 'advertising secrets written', 'secrets written word'],
["12 Alex's Adventures in Numberland Paperback by Alex Bellos\n", '12 alex s', 'alex s adventures', 's adventures numberland', 'adventures numberland paperback', 'numberland paperback alex', 'paperback alex bellos']
]
```

Now how do I compare n-grams to find the duplicates.

I am looking for a output where it groups the duplicates. Something like:

```
[
    [1 A Course of Pure Mathematics by G. H. Hardy\n],
    [9 A Course of Pure Mathematics (Cambridge Mathematical Library) 10th Edition by G. H. Hardy]
],
[
    [2 Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices by Robert C. Martin],
    [8 Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices]
]
....
```

Comment: What output do you desire if there are multiple duplicates for an entry ("Beginners Course of Pure Mathematics", "Comprehensive Course of Pure Mathematics", "Comprehensive Course of Pure Physics")? Should the entry be duplicated to each group?

Comment: For now, I want to keep it simple. So, after the first match it is a duplicate. All duplicated will be in same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP Here, The solution seems to be:

```
import re
from nltk.util import ngrams

OriginalBooksList = list()
booksAfterRemovingStopWords = list()
booksWithNGrams = list()
stopWords = ['I', 'a', 'about', 'an', 'are', 'as', 'at', 'be', 'by', 'com', 'for', 'from', 'how', 'in', 'is', 'it', 'of', 'on', 'or', 'that', 'the', 'this', 'to', 'was', 'the',
             'and', 'A', 'About', 'An', 'Are', 'As', 'At', 'Be', 'By', 'Com', 'For', 'From', 'How', 'In', 'Is', 'It', 'Of', 'On', 'Or', 'That', 'The', 'This', 'To', 'Was', 'The', 'And']

with open('UnifiedBookList.txt') as fin:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(fin):
        OriginalBooksList.append(line)
        line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', line)  # replace punctuation with space
        line = re.sub(' +', ' ', line)  # replace multiple space with one
        line = line.lower()  # to lower case
        if line.strip() and len(line.split()) > 2:  # line can not be empty and line must have more than 2 words
            booksAfterRemovingStopWords.append(' '.join([i for i in line.split(
            ) if i not in stopWords]))  # Remove Stop Words And Make Sentence


for line_no, line in enumerate(booksAfterRemovingStopWords):
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    output = list(ngrams(tokens, 3))
    temp = list()

    temp.append(OriginalBooksList[line_no])  # Adding original line
    for x in output:  # Adding n-grams
        temp.append(' '.join(x))
    booksWithNGrams.append(temp)

while booksWithNGrams:
    first_element = booksWithNGrams.pop(0)
    x = 0
    for mylist in booksWithNGrams:
        if set(first_element) & set(mylist):
            if x == 0:
                print(first_element[0])
                x = 1
                # print(set(first_element) & set(mylist))
            print(mylist[0])
            booksWithNGrams.remove(mylist)
    x = 0
```